# pq o loop while True acessa o if e o else em sequência a cada loop completo nesse código?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loop, while

```
#! /usr/bin/python3

valor = int(input("Digite o valor a pagar: "))

cedulas = 0
atual = 50
apagar = valor

while True:
    if atual <= apagar:
        apagar = apagar - atual
        cedulas += 1
    else:
        print("%d cedula(s) de R$%d" %(cedulas, atual))
        if apagar == 0:
            break
        elif atual == 50:
            atual = 20
        elif atual == 20:
            atual = 10
        elif atual == 10:
            atual = 5
        elif atual == 5:
            atual = 1
        cedulas = 0
```

não entendo como o loop acessa o primeiro if e o else na sequência dentro do while True. O else não deveria ser acessado somente quando o primeiro if do código for falso? como esse código funciona linha a linha?, alguém poderia me explicar?, lembrando que sou iniciante em programação.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não entra nos dois (if e else) na mesma volta do ciclo.

O "problema" é que visto ser `while True...` ele vai fazer várias voltas, entrando no if (caso a condição se verifique) e decrementando 50 (valor inicial de `atual`) ao valor de `apagar`, até que ao momento que `apagar` for menor que `atual`, aí já vai entrar no else. Podes testar isto fazendo um `print(valor, apagar)` dentro do ciclo, e colocando o valor apagar a 200 por exemplo.

Se quiseres fazer um break na primeira vez que entra no if, deves explicitar.

Explicação visual:

```
valor = int(input("Digite o valor a pagar: "))

cedulas = 0
atual = 50
apagar = valor

while True:
    print(valor, atual, apagar) # acrescentei isto para perceberes o que se passa
    if atual <= apagar:
        apagar = apagar - atual
        cedulas += 1
    else:
        print("%d cedula(s) de R$%d" %(cedulas, atual))
        if apagar == 0:
            break
        elif atual == 50:
            atual = 20
        elif atual == 20:
            atual = 10
        elif atual == 10:
            atual = 5
        elif atual == 5:
            atual = 1
        cedulas = 0
```

A saída do programa com `apagar` sendo 200:

> 200 50 200
>       200 50 150
>       200 50 100
>       200 50 50
>       200 50 0 <-- só aqui depois deste print, na mesma volta, é que vai entrar no else 
>       4 cedula(s) de R$50

Aqui podes ver que nas primeiras 4 voltas entramos no if, porque `apagar` nestas 4 voltas ainda era maior ou igual que `atual`.

Lembrando que atual também vai alterando a partir do momento que antramos no `else`, assim sendo, neste caso, mais tarde ou mais cedo vamos parar dentro o `if apagar == 0:` que é o que 'faz' `break` ao ciclo

Se quiseres sair do ciclo ao entrar no if:

```
...
if atual <= apagar:
    apagar = apagar - atual
    cedulas += 1
    break
...
```